# Apply a layer style to all frames

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I want to apply a same style to ten layers. The problem is that I'm working with gif and for some reason the layers style only apply to that one frame even tho i selected all frames. I do not want group them because grouping doesn't allow clipping mask. is there a way to apply layer style to all frames without the use of group? thanks in advance.

Comment: Right-click on a layer > "copy layer style" and then select multiple layers, right-click one of them and > "paste layer style". The Alt+drag method is probably faster/more convenient for <10 layers but with >10 layers copy&paste is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible but a fast way to do this is to quick-duplicate the style with <kbd>alt</kbd> + drag or <kbd>option</kbd> + drag

[image: Demo of quick style duplication]

Answer (score 1):

select your frames, add a layer effect. Only the first selected has the effect, BUT reselect all frames, click again like you are going to modify the effect and only click ok, now all of them should have the effect applied !